# How can I store the current frame's MVP matrix (Or any other data about the current frame) so that I can use it in the next frame?

Tags: unity, shaders

I've read several articles about motion blur and all were made with OpenGL. There is no equivalent of MVP matrix in C# scripts, so I wondered if the data could be stored on the GPU itself.

Is it possible?

Comment: If you want motion blur, why not just use [the build-in post processing filter](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/post-processing-effects-motion-blur-2019-3)?

Comment: I'm not trying to implement motion blur, but I'm thinking of creating a new effect using the techniques used to create motion blur. One major hurdle is that I can't find any resources on using data from the previous frame.

Comment: Are you looking for [`Camera.previousViewProjectionMatrix`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-previousViewProjectionMatrix.html)? To get the "M", you'd just have to store the `transform.localToWorldMatrix` of your object of interest from last frame, which you can do in an ordinary member variable you overwrite at the end of each frame. If you need help writing that script, can you edit your question to clarify where you've run into difficulty with this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple script that saves the MVP matrix used to render an object each frame, and caches it in a `PreviousMVP` variable to read next frame.

You can use [`Material.SetMatrix`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetMatrix.html) or [`Shader.SetGlobalMatrix`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Shader.SetGlobalMatrix.html) to provide these matrices to your shader materials.

```cs
public class MVPSaver : MonoBehaviour
{
    [field:SerializeField]
    public Matrix4x4 CurrentMVP {get; private set;}

    [field:SerializeField]
    public Matrix4x4 PreviousMVP {get; private set;}

    // Called when this object is about to be rendered.
    // Snapshot the MVP matrix used for that rendering.
    void OnWillRenderObject() {

        var camera = Camera.current;

        var model = transform.localToWorldMatrix;

        var view = camera.worldToCameraMatrix;

        var projection = camera.projectionMatrix;

        // Unity works with column vectors, meaning matrices
        // combine in right-to-left order, so MVP = P * V * M.
        CurrentMVP = projection * view * model;
    }

    // Called after the object has been rendered.
    // Pass the latest MVP matrix into the previous slot.
    void OnRenderObject() {
        PreviousMVP = CurrentMVP;
    }
}
```