# Is there any way to store values in vertex shader such that they can be used in the next frame?

Tags: unity, shaders, vertex-shader

As I understand, the values assigned in the vertex shader aren't persistent and storing them doesn't do anything. I want to store the MVP matrix in another variable to be used in the next frame.

```
float4x4 curmvp;
float4x4 premvp;

v2f vert (appdata v){
    curmvp = UNITY_MATRIX_MVP;
    v2f o;

    posi = mul(curmvp, v.vertex);
    preposi = mul(premvp, v.vertex);

    o.curpos = posi;

    premvp = curmvp;
    return o;
    }
```

I'm thinking of looking into compute buffers, but they seem to be very taxing on the CPU.

Comment: Instead of hoping to preserve the value on the gpu you should instead look at passing the previous value by grabbing it and preserving it on the cpu and passing it as another uniform value.

Comment: What ratchet freak describes is the only way to do this, short of writing it out to a texture or other buffer in a compute shader, which is really just more work to accomplish the same thing. Unity uploads plenty of matrix uniforms every frame, so you will not break the bank by adding one more. [I described how to do this in an earlier answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/206756/39518).

Comment: @DMGregory I tried your solution, but it doesn't produce the expected results. The pixels appear transparent. Also, the matrices in C# don't work in shaders at all.

Comment: If you'd like to edit this question to document how you tried applying that solution, including all code and scene setup needed to create a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example, then we can help you solve it. C# matrices work just fine in shaders, if you use them correctly — I have years of experience doing just that. But I'll need to see your code before I can tell you where you've used them incorrectly.